# Angular2 Draw Rectangle on Canvas with Mouse

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I am new to angular2 and canvases and I am trying to create a component that first draws an image onto a canvas and then the user can draw rectangles on that image with their mouse (in a click and drag fashion).  This is what I have so far which almost works as intended.

```
@Component({
    selector:'app-annotation',
    template:`                    
        <canvas #myCanvas width="400" height="400" style="background:lightgray;" (mousedown)="mdEvent($event)" (mouseup)="muEvent($event)" (mousemove)="mmEvent($event)"></canvas>
    `
})
export class ObjectDetectionComponent implements OnInit{

    startX:number=null;
    startY:number=null;
    drag=false;

    @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas:ElementRef;

    mdEvent(e){
        //persist starting position
        this.startX=e.clientX;
        this.startY=e.clientY;
        this.drag=true;
    }

    mmEvent(e){

        if(this.drag){

            //redraw image on canvas
            let base_image = new Image();
            base_image.src = 'https://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/10826363/thumb/1.jpg';
            let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
            base_image.onload = function(){
                context.canvas.height=base_image.height;
                context.canvas.width=base_image.width;
                context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
            };

            //draw rectangle on canvas
            let x = this.startX - this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            let y= this.startY- this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            let w = e.clientX -this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left - x;
            let h = e.clientY -this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - y;
            context.setLineDash([6]);
            context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
        }
    }

    muEvent(e){
        //draw final rectangle on canvas
        let x = this.startX - this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let y= this.startY- this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        let w = e.clientX -this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left - x;
        let h = e.clientY -this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - y;
        this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").setLineDash([6]);
        this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").strokeRect(x, y, w, h);

        this.drag=false;
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        //draw image on canvas
        let base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'https://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/10826363/thumb/1.jpg';
        let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        base_image.onload = function(){
            context.canvas.height=base_image.height;
            context.canvas.width=base_image.width;
            context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem here is that when the mouse is clicked and held down, the rectangle only shows if there is mouse movement - but I want the current rectangle to be still be shown as long as the mouse is still clicked.  This is sort of unexpected since in `mmEvent()` the rectangle is drawn after the image is redrawn so I would expect the rectangle to be the last thing drawn after any mouse move event - however maybe the `base_image.onload()` callback is messing with the timing of that.  Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

UPDATE:

drawing the rectangle inside the callback seems to fix it

```
mmEvent(e) {

        if (this.drag) {

            //redraw image on canvas
            let base_image = new Image();
            base_image.src = 'https://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/10826363/thumb/1.jpg';
            let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
            let sx = this.startX;
            let sy = this.startY;

            let canvasTop = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            let canvasLeft = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;

            base_image.onload = function () {
                context.canvas.height = base_image.height;
                context.canvas.width = base_image.width;
                context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

                //draw rectangle on canvas
                let x = sx - canvasLeft;
                let y = sy - canvasTop;
                let w = e.clientX - canvasLeft - x;
                let h = e.clientY - canvasTop - y;
                context.setLineDash([6]);
                context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
            };


        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really well done

Comment: My only suggestion would be to change ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit so that the element is able to initialise before accessing it.